# Add or subtract numbers from different viewports in Swift4

Tags: swift4, xcode9.3

I am new here and would like to ask a question that has been working for me for days. I'm just learning Swift 4 and I've come quite a long way. I really do not know what to do any more, and my books on swift do not help me either.

I have created a small testapp, in which should simply be charged.

There are 5 view controllers. The first one has 4 buttons to get to one of the other 4 and to enter a number there in a text box. This number is then output in the first viewcontroller in a label. The numbers are displayed and even the last entered number is displayed again after a restart of the app.

But now I want to charge off the numbers in the first viewcontroller. How can I fix the code?

My Viewports:

[my viewports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5aDn.jpg)

code from main viewport:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, sendValue1, sendValue2, sendValue3, sendValue4 {



    @IBOutlet weak var value1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var value2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var value3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var value4: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var calculatedValue1: UILabel! // here i want to see the calculated value like from the label 1-4...value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 = ???
    @IBOutlet weak var calculatedValue2: UILabel! // here the same like in claculatedValue1 value but with "-" or "*" or something else...




    func value1Data(data: String) {
        value1.text = data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value1.text, forKey: "value1")
    }
    func value2Data(data: String) {
        value2.text = data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value2.text, forKey: "value2")
    }
    func value3Data(data: String) {
        value3.text = data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value3.text, forKey: "value3")
    }
    func value4Data(data: String) {
        value4.text = data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value4.text, forKey: "value4")
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let lastValue1Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "value1") as? String {
            value1.text = lastValue1Data
        }
        if let lastValue2Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "value2") as? String {
            value2.text = lastValue2Data
        }
        if let lastValue3Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "value3") as? String {
            value3.text = lastValue3Data
        }
        if let LastValue4Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "value4") as? String {
            value4.text = LastValue4Data
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "VC1" {
            let SendingVC1:  Value1ViewController = segue.destination as! Value1ViewController
            SendingVC1.delegate = self
        }
        if segue.identifier == "VC2" {
            let SendingVC2: Value2ViewController = segue.destination as! Value2ViewController
            SendingVC2.delegate = self
        }
        if segue.identifier == "VC3" {
            let SendingVC3: Value3ViewController = segue.destination as! Value3ViewController
            SendingVC3.delegate = self
        }
        if segue.identifier == "VC4" {
            let SendingVC4: Value4ViewController = segue.destination as! Value4ViewController
            SendingVC4.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToView1(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }
```

and the code from one of the other four:

```
import UIKit

protocol sendValue1 {
    func value1Data(data: String)
}

class Value1ViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: sendValue1? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var textValue1: UITextField!

    @IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
        if delegate != nil {
            if textValue1.text != nil {
                let data = textValue1.text
                delegate?.value1Data(data: data!)
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to come up with an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you really need 4 subviews?

Comment: yes, i really need them.

Comment: Eventually you might really need 4 subviewcontrollers... but from quickly scanning your example it seems that you would only need 2 to have the same problem. Hence, your example is not minimal and you should reduce it.

Comment: I really need all four of the UI Desgins, maybe even a fifth.

Answer (score 0):

why is the result always nil here?

```
let a = Float(value3.text!) ?? 0
let b = Float(value4.text!) ?? 0
let SUM = a + b
calculatedValue1.text = "\(SUM)" + "m"
```

No matter what I do, the numbers are not processed ...